# Java: Is there any way to read file until a certain character

Tags: java

I am new in Java Language. Is there any way to read a file until a certain character and make it loop again.
sample text file will look like this.

```
    No.    Title     Score
    1       abc        9
    Info: adajiodasjdsajkldas adhq sdahdu
    dasjkdajkldsa adwq
    dasjlkda qe quei qoep
    No.    Title     Score
    2       abc        9
    No.    Title     Score
    3       abc        9
    Info: dasjkdaj aks
    dasjlkda
    No.    Title     Score
    4       abc        9
    Info: dasjkdaj dahjkqi
    dasjlkda
```

What i need is to read the beginning until the score and the rest will be ignore and make it read finish those stuff after that make a new loop again.
This is how i code this and i do not know how to eliminate/read the Info until the new No. Meanwhile the Info can be multiple lines or it could be empty
This is how i code but is not completed, i am asking for help to make it complete.

```
    Scanner read = new Scanner (new File("Student.txt"));
    read.useDelimiter("[\\s]+");
    String Eliminate[] = new String[99];
        String No[] = new String[100];
        String Title[] = new String[100];
        String Score[] = new String[3];
        int i =0;
    while (read.hasNext())
    {   
            Eliminate[i] = read.nextLine(); //eliminate first line
            No[i] = read.next();
            Title[i] = read.next();
            Score[i] = read.next();

            System.out.println(Eliminate[i] + "\n" + No[i] + " " + Title[i] + " " + Score[i] + "\n" ); // just for debugging
            i++;
        }
        read.close();
```

Comment: yes, there always is. It's called `EOF`. In Java usually it means that `stream.read()` returns `-1`

Comment: Instead of re-reading a certain portion of the file, why don't you just read once and then reuse the information?  Certain types of Java streams can only be read once, by the way.

Comment: Do you consider to use XML instead of flatfile ? You could then easily manipulate data with JAXB.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
while (read.hasNext())
{   
    if (read.next().equals("No.")){
        Eliminate[i] = read.nextLine(); //eliminate first line
        No[i] = read.next();
        Title[i] = read.next();
        Score[i] = read.next();

        System.out.println(Eliminate[i] + "\n" + No[i] + " " + Title[i] + " " + Score[i] + "\n" ); // just for debugging
        i++;
    }
}
```